# using sed to extract a few key value pairs

Tags: bash, sed, grep

we have the following json:

```
CREDENTIALS={
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROAISP5PIZYVEX", 
        "Arn": "arn"
    }, 
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "lWUZ+C+pzGroJd+575kOIVqgl", 
        "SessionToken": "FwoGZXIvYXdzEGQaDHhM75xUifznTTzTnSK7Aer4WveFRcMqaiQFjOnbGRq/+UF8k0cpX2xc35epGjV49hf26LHV4+MOj0fyTk8w1aMk2ZH5Kmj9CZ6jKcYQtebUiCFRhmufK+VXovveD1nx9XAgka", 
        "Expiration": "2020-01-09T03:21:27Z", 
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAWN6"
    }
}
```

I need to use `sed` to get SecretAccessKey, SessionToken and AccessKeyId. Not sure how, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get SecretAccessKey:

```
sed -nr '/SecretAccessKey/{s/.*"SecretAccessKey": "([^"]+)".*/\1/;p;}' file
```

First, we suppress the default printing(`-n`) of each line. For the line contains `SecretAccessKey`, we then try to get the value of `secretaccesskey` by having a pattern where we look for value between the quotes and then print the match.

Comment: This is certainly the simplest, and for small files, making 3 passes of the file to get the three variables out will be fine, but for a larger input file, sed can generate a smaller fragment containing all 3 tags in a single pass, which would then be processed by bash regex.

Answer (score 1):

The question has the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) tag, and indeed using a JSON-aware utility such as jq makes sense, so here is an example of how jq could be used, assuming CREDENTIALS holds valid JSON:

```
jq -r '.Credentials | (.SecretAccessKey, .SessionToken, .AccessKeyId)' <<< $CREDENTIALS
```

With the given sample, the output would be:

```
lWUZ+C+pzGroJd+575kOIVqgl
FwoGZXIvYXdzEGQaDHhM75xUifznTTzTnSK7Aer4WveFRcMqaiQFjOnbGRq/+UF8k0cpX2xc35epGjV49hf26LHV4+MOj0fyTk8w1aMk2ZH5Kmj9CZ6jKcYQtebUiCFRhmufK+VXovveD1nx9XAgka
ASIAWN6
```